# I am just trying to pass some javascript value from function func() to the tag "p".But it's not happening.Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A part of the Html body:

```
<div id="d">
    <div class="imge">
        <img src="meter.jpg" width="450" height="350" alt="" />
        <h2>1234578  kWh</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript function.

```
function func()
{
 document.getElementById("d").getElementsByClassName("imge").getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML="String"
}
```

Is the above syntax correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `func()` should be `document.getElementById("d").getElementsByClassName("imge")[0].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML="String"`

as `getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Answer (score 1):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method returns a HTMLCollection, so you at least need to use some index, like `[0]` to get the first element from this collection:

```
document.getElementById("d").getElementsByClassName("imge")[0].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerHTML="String"
```

However it's much more convenient to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to retrieve HTML element by CSS selector:

```
function func() {
    document.querySelector('#d .imge h2').innerHTML = "String";
}
```